# removing elements from a vector with O(1) runtime

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

"Write a function which takes as an input an object of vector type
removes an element at the rank k in the constant time, O(1) [constant]. Assume that the order of elements does not matter."

I thought I might have had an idea about this. But, as I started to try by using .erase(), I looked up what the big-O notation was and found out it was O(n),as in linear relation. I can't think of any other way at the moment. I don't want any code, but I think pseudo code will at least point me in the right direction if anyone can help

Comment: Does removed in O(1) mean the value at that location is deleted/nulled, or does it mean everything past that point is moved down?

Comment: @ruakh yes. rank k basically means the index

Comment: @StarPilot This is where it is very vague. tbh, I don't know if just the element is supposed to be deleted, or if it is supposed to be deleted and everything past is also moved down

Comment: Of course there is a solution. The order does not matter and you can only remove the very last object in O(1) as you don't need to move or reallocate in only that exact case.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> Assume that the order of elements does not matter.

This is what you need to pay attention to.

Suppose you have a vector

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

and you want to remove the 3. You can turn this into

```
0 1 2 6 4 5
```

in O(1) without any issues.

Comment: Oh I see what is going on. This makes sense. Thank you guys.

Comment: Plus 1. Damn, he was quicker than me by 14 seconds.

Answer (score 14):

Actually, there is a way to do it.  Here is the pseudocode:

1. If the element you are trying to remove is the last element in the vector, remove it, done.
2. Read the last element of the vector and write it over the element-to-be-removed.
3. Remove the last element of the vector.

Answer (score 2):

You can [`swap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap) and [`pop_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/pop_back) in constant time.

```
std::swap(vec.back(), vec[rank]);
vec.pop_back();
```

Comment: That's wasteful. Just do `vec[i] = std::move(vec.back()); vec.pop_back();`. No reason to actually do a swap when `vec[rank]` is gonna get destroyed anyway.